# Unable to resolve "styled-components" from "node_modules\react-simple-chatbot"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, chatbot, styled-components

I am trying to run my react application using expo cli and getting the following error while building the bundle.js.

Following is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChatBot from 'react-simple-chatbot';

let withTextToSpeech = [
  {
    id: '1',
    component: <TextToSpeech msg="Hi" />,
    trigger: '2',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    user: true,
    trigger: '3',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    component: <TextToSpeech msg='What is your name?' />,
    trigger: '4',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    user: true,
    trigger: '5',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    component: <TextToSpeech msg = 'Nice to meet you!' />,
    trigger: 6,
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    component: <TextToSpeech msg='How can i help you?' />,
    trigger: 'search',
  },
  {
    id: 'search',
    user: true,
    trigger: '7',
  }
]

let withoutTextToSpeech = [
  {
    id: '1',
    message: 'hi',
    trigger: '2',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    user: true,
    trigger: '3',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    message: 'What is your name?',
    trigger: '4',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    user: true,
    trigger: '5',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    message: 'Hi {previousValue}, nice to meet you!',
    trigger: 6,
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    message: 'How can i help you?',
    trigger: 'search',
  },
  {
    id: 'search',
    user: true,
    trigger: '7',
  }
]



class App extends Component {

  constructor( props ){
    super( props )

    this.state= {
      textToSpeech: true,
      steps : withTextToSpeech,
      sessionId: sessionId
    }
    withTextToSpeech.push(ChatMessageElement)
    withoutTextToSpeech.push(ChatMessageElement)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.textToSpeech)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ChatBot
          headerTitle="ChatBot"
          recognitionEnable={true}
          steps={this.state.textToSpeech ? withTextToSpeech : withoutTextToSpeech}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yarn add styled-components


import styled from 'styled-components'
```

Comment: I think simple-react-chatbot has the dependency for styled component what is the use of using some library if it doesn’t download internal dependency.

Comment: I have not used react-simple-chatbot but I assume there is an error in the dependency tree of the package which is not an unusual problem in the npm world. You could probably file an issue on github. Anyway I guess the answer solved the problem?

Comment: I didn’t tried tho I will and if it solved my problem I will be happy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
npm install styled-components
```